# Unity Partcle system same size no matter how far the camera is zoomed out

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I have a particle system and have a zoom-out thing for my camera, but when i zoom out the particles are the same size as normal!

Does anyone know why that may be?

This is the original camera size:

[image: Original camera size]

This is the zoomed-out one:

[image: Zoomed-out camera]

I want it to look like the original but zoomed out like everything not big blobs as what they look like now

Thanks!

EDIT:

Added the particle system settings

[image: Particle system settings 1]

[image: Particle system settings 2]

Comment: Are you referring to the gradient between white and dark grey? Assuming you're using the standard particle shader do you have soft particles enabled?

Comment: ParticleSystem => Renderer => Min Particle Size may be causing such behaviour

Comment: @PawełŁęgowski the min particle size is set to 0.

Comment: @Absinthe I will add what i have on in my particle system to the question

Comment: What shader are you using for the material? It it the unlit sprite shader? If so try using a particle shader instead.

Comment: It does the same thing and it changed what the particles looked like.

Comment: How are you "zooming" the camera?

Comment: changing the orthographic size.